# Angular 2 http.post error on Firefox and IE

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, angular2-http

The following code works without problems in Chrome, but in Firefox and IE 11 an error does not permit to the post request to be fired.
So the server does not receive any request, the error is inside the request code.
The error that I receive does not contain useful informations.

The back end has CORS enabled and it works correctly with Chrome.

**In IE 11 the error is:**

`XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.`

The method handleError returns in the console

`Response with status: 0  for URL: null`

This is a screenshot image of it [IE11 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJZw6.png)

**In Firefox the error is:**

`Response { _body=Event error,  status=0,  ok=false,  more...}`

---

```
login(username, password): Observable<boolean> {

    let reqScopes: string[] = ["login.login", "invoices.read"];
    let options = new RequestOptions({withCredentials:true });

    return this.http.post(AppSettings.ApiEndpoint+'/login'+AppSettings.xdebug, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password,scopes:reqScopes}),options)
    .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
        if (token) {
            // set token property
            this.token = token;

            // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('webinfoUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));

            // return true to indicate successful login
            return true;
        } else {
            // return false to indicate failed login
            return false;
        }
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
    //.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}

private handleError(error: any) {
    console.log( error);       
    return Observable.throw( error.status );
}
```

Comment: Two days working on it without success, still Chrome OK and Firefox and IE KO

Comment: Any updates on this? Having the same issue in FF